# column image behave as background image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two columns using flexbox but does not have to use flexbox. just using it at the moment but am open to other options. The left side is content with a width of `450px` and the right column I have an image that needs to behave as a background image but not use css background property. Is there a way to set the image size / image column and have it overflow out of containers and not push the left column content?

setting container widths and using relative positioning but not scaling or behaving as I would like

```css
.row--flex {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.content-col--450 {
  max-width: 450px;
}

.content-col {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 97px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.image-col {
  padding-left: 10px;
}


}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container--outer">
  <div class="row--flex">
    <!--content-->
    <div class="content-col content-col--450">
      <div class="title-row">
        <h2>
          testing h2
        </h2>
      </div>

      <div class="content-row">
        <p class="p-margin-bottom">
          testing P
        </p>

        <p class="lead">
          download test
        </p>

        <button class="button--arrow">
                        <span class="button--text">download now</span>
                    </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end content-->

    <!--image-->
    <div class="image-col">
      <img src="/img/right-image.png" alt="right column image" class="image-test">
    </div>
    <!--end image-->
  </div>
```

column 450 stay in place and image overflow out of containers and behave as BG image

Comment: Please add a screenshot of how you want it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this?

```css
.row--flex {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.content-col--450 {
  /* max-width: 450px; */
  flex-basis: 450px;
}

.content-col {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 97px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.image-col {
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: 450px;
  align-self: stretch;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.image-test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container--outer">
  <div class="row--flex">
    <div class="content-col content-col--450">
      <div class="title-row">
        <h2>
          testing h2
        </h2>
      </div>

      <div class="content-row">
        <p class="p-margin-bottom">
          testing P
        </p>

        <p class="lead">
          download test
        </p>

        <button class="button--arrow">
                    <span class="button--text">download now</span>
                </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="image-col">
      <img class="image-test" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="right column image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```